# Call unobtrusive javascript by timer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update some list dynamically on one page in my Rails application. I know about unobtrusive javascript and how to call it by links and forms. But, is there any beautiful way to call unobstrusive javascript by timer.

Comment: I solved the problem using $.getScript() method, that called by timer.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like

```
<ul data-behaviour='list-updater'>
 ...
</ul>
```

and in a javascript asset file

```
$.fn.updaterComponent = function() {
   var timer= function () { ... };
   setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

$( function() { 
  $("[data-behaviour='list-updater']").updaterComponent();
});
```

It will be pretty unobtrusive :)

Comment: can you be more explicit on what do you mean not in a rails context ?

Comment: I want ot have some ability not to make the form by javascript (instead just make render 'form') and to have ability to get some backend variables from the controller, so the way you offer is not unobtrusive...